# Filtering object values in django

Tags: python, django

I have below code in my signals.py :

```
student.detailinfo_set.all().filter(inf="204X1001")
```

`student` and `detailinfo` are two models in models.py and they have many-to-many relation in between.

When I print `student.detailinfo_set.all().filter(inf="204X1001")` to a file from signals.py, I get below output:

```
<DetailInfo: 700101 -  Jack Marcher/2018-09-19/Trans X101 / 204X1001 / Pro/Y2>
<DetailInfo: 700101 -  Jack Marcher/2018-09-21/Trans X1 / 204X22 / Pro/Y2>
<DetailInfo: 700101 -  Jack Marcher/2018-09-11/Trans X102 / 204X1001 / Pro/Y2>
<DetailInfo: 700101 -  Jack Marcher/2018-09-10/Trans X1 / 204X22 / Pro/Y2>
```

I just want to filter 4th columns of each row which are "204X1001", so that it will print just 2 lines to the file.

---

Solved by Daniil Mashkin's answer below: `student.detailinfo_set.all().filter(inf="204X1001")` usage was wrong in my code. 
The correct usage is `student.detailinfo_set.filter(inf="204X1001")`

Comment: I would advice you to share your model. Right now it is guesswork what the fourth column is, etc. Furthermore it is strictly speaking possible that this is not an individual database column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter query you should use the [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method. If `4th column` named like `fourth_column` you should use the following code.

```
student.detailinfo_set.filter(fourth_column="204X1001")
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Solved. I was using student.detailinfo_set.all().filter(fourth_column="204X1001")  but i removed  the all() and now it is working as student.detailinfo_set.filter(fourth_column="204X1001")